# DB query returns corrupted data on Android

Tags: android, database, image, sqlite, cursor

I have an SQLite DB with a sample table, which is stored in the assets/ folder.

This DB contains a single table, one of the columns is BLOB containing a BMP image. I may read/write this image flawlessly using JDBC on the host machine.

Then the data is accessed from the emulator using the following code:

```
final Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, FROM, null, null, null, null, null);

if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    byte[] icon = cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndex(SearchEngines.ICON));
    // ...
```

But the attempt to decode retreived image fails:

```
final Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(icon , 0, icon.length);
```

I get null result and the following in the log:

```
DEBUG/skia(374): --- decoder->decode returned false
```

After this, I dumped the blob array into the file and compared with the original image. And it was a complete surprise, because the only uncovered difference was that all the 0x00 bytes were replaced with 0x25 0x30 sequences in the retreived blob:

```
0x00 -> 0x25 0x30 // %0
```

Besides that, all the data was intact. What the heck?

**Update 1.** After pulling the DB from the emulator (adb pull) the data it contains is corrupted (same %0 symbols). So, the problem is either in DB itself or implementation/usage of query/getBlob or other DB access code.

**Update 2.** **Seems that it's wrong** As far as I understand, SQLite supports 2 ways of storing large objects: TEXT and BLOB. TEXT columns don't contain 0x00 bytes, and in BLOBs 0x00 is translated into %0 (what a coincidence!). So, it seems that what I get is internal representation, not the actual data.

**Update 3.** Code for adding to DB is the following:

```
private void save(Connection conn, String id, String fileName) throws SQLException, IOException {
    final String sql = "UPDATE " + TABLE_NAME + " SET " + BLOB_COLUMN_NAME + " = ? WHERE " + ID_COLUMN_NAME + " = ?";
    System.out.println("Executing: " + sql);

    final PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    pstmt.setInt(2, Integer.valueOf(id));

    File fBlob = new File(fileName);
    FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(fBlob);

    byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) fBlob.length()];
    int rc = is.read(bytes);
    assert (rc == bytes.length);
    System.out.println("Total size: " + rc);

    pstmt.setBytes(1, bytes);
    pstmt.execute();
}
```

Comment: Isn't that special? Three questions . . . Did this work before, or is it all new code? Can you isolate the problem to either the db or the application code by writing the bitmap to a file instead of storing it in the database? Also, what's the result of `select typeof(your_blob_column) from your_table_name;`?

Comment: Answering to your questions: (1) no, it is not possible to narrow it down to a few lines of changed code (it failed as soon it was implemented), (2) the problem is definitely in the DB: after retrieving the DB from the emulator (using adb pull) it contains the same garbled data.

Comment: @Catcall: I'll check `select typeof` asap.

Comment: Can you prepare the BLOB for inserting, then decode it instead of inserting it? That might point you in the right direction.

Comment: @Andy, There are a couple misstatements in your Update 2: SQLite TEXT columns may contain 0x00 bytes, though text with embedded NULs may be hard to use; SQLite BLOB functions do not modify the data, so this must be happening in the Java wrapper or DB access code. Show us what code you are using to insert the BLOBs.

Comment: @Catcall: `select typeof` says that it's `blob`

Comment: @DougCurrie: Thanks, I've attached the JDBC code. For now, I just store names of the images in the DB, fetching the actual data as a resource from the assets/ folder at run-time.